# Postgres Explain - how to optimize

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, explain

Performance is growing increasingly poor.
Using explain, I see that there is a sequential scan in a nested loop - which is likely the performance issue.  What I do not know is: how do I improve this?

Here is a link to the query and the explain output: https://explain.depesz.com/s/zmzp
I'll include them here, too:

Query:

```
'''
SELECT
    "assets".*
FROM
    "assets"
    INNER JOIN "devices" ON "devices"."asset_id" = "assets"."id"
WHERE
    "assets"."archived_at" IS NULL
    AND "assets"."archive_number" IS NULL
    AND "assets"."assettype_id" = 3
    AND ((assets.lastseendate >= NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days')
        AND ((devices.stop_time IS NULL)
            OR (devices.stop_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days')
            OR (devices.launch_time IS NOT NULL
                AND devices.launch_time > devices.stop_time)))
'''
```

And here is the explain output:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..255815.01 rows=11889 width=218) (actual time=0.049..2187.719 rows=359445 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1499737 read=75
  I/O Timings: read=5.382
  ->  Seq Scan on assets  (cost=0.00..117666.24 rows=27484 width=218) (actual time=0.035..770.720 rows=359543 loops=1)
        Filter: ((archived_at IS NULL) AND (archive_number IS NULL) AND (assettype_id = 3) AND (lastseendate >= (now() - 'P30D'::interval)))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2539219
        Buffers: shared hit=59691
  ->  Index Scan using devices_asset_id_ix on devices  (cost=0.43..5.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=359543)
        Index Cond: (asset_id = assets.id)
        Filter: ((stop_time IS NULL) OR (stop_time >= (now() - 'P30D'::interval)) OR ((launch_time IS NOT NULL) AND (launch_time > stop_time)))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 0
        Buffers: shared hit=1440046 read=75
        I/O Timings: read=5.382
Planning Time: 1.055 ms
Execution Time: 2264.396 ms
```

The only relevant index is this one:

```
devices_asset_id_ix
```

UPDATE:  I've added several indexes as listed here:

```
add_index :devices, [:asset_id, :stop_time, :launch_time], name: "device_online_idx"
add_index :devices, [:asset_id, :stop_time]
add_index :devices, [:asset_id, :launch_time]
add_index :devices, :stop_time
add_index :devices, :launch_time

add_index :assets, [:assettype_id, :archived_at, :archive_number, :lastseendate], name: "asset_unexpired_idx"
add_index :assets, :assettype_id
add_index :assets, :archived_at
add_index :assets, :archive_number
add_index :assets, :lastseendate
```

This has changed the explain to look like this:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..179162.78 rows=11872 width=218) (actual time=0.050..1680.166 rows=359011 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1726893 read=33
  I/O Timings: read=0.226
  ->  Index Scan using asset_unexpired_idx on assets  (cost=0.56..41125.44 rows=27451 width=218) (actual time=0.037..315.869 rows=359110 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((assettype_id = 3) AND (archived_at IS NULL) AND (archive_number IS NULL) AND (lastseendate >= (now() - 'P30D'::interval)))
        Buffers: shared hit=288537
  ->  Index Scan using devices_asset_id_ix on devices  (cost=0.43..5.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=359110)
        Index Cond: (asset_id = assets.id)
        Filter: ((stop_time IS NULL) OR (stop_time >= (now() - 'P30D'::interval)) OR ((launch_time IS NOT NULL) AND (launch_time > stop_time)))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 0
        Buffers: shared hit=1438356 read=33
        I/O Timings: read=0.226
Planning Time: 1.322 ms
Execution Time: 1757.047 ms
```

This got a 25% improvement.  Is there any way to substantially improve this further?

Comment: Please _edit_ your question to clearly show the SQL query by itself.  Also include all index definitions.

Comment: We need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: I've added the one relevant index definition and changed the explain to have the ANALYZE AND BUFFERS options.  NOTE: this is using development (test) data ... not the actual production data.

Comment: Your test database should have the same size as production.  Otherwise, it is useless for tuning.

Comment: it looks like I'd benefit from adding indexes to asset.assettype_id, asset.lastseendate, asset.archived_at, and asset.archived_number as well as devices.stop_time and devices.launch_time

Comment: rows=1348 and rows=1696, that's not even close to the 10m (million?) records that you mention. The query runs in 1.7 milliseconds, it might be slightly faster with some indexes, but don't expect a huge improvement compared to the current speed.

Comment: Updated to use production data

Comment: What about either (a) moving the stop_time and launch_time fields up from devices table into the assets table to avoid the join -- this should remove the nested loop.  Or (b) precalculating the "online" status as a boolean based on devices.stop_time and launch_time to have a single column index on devices?  Would either of those help substantially?

Answer (score 1):

Try a [compound b-tree index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) like so

```
CREATE INDEX assets_type_archive_date
    ON assets
       (assettype_id, archived_at, archive_number, lastseendate)
```

It should help you filter your assets table efficiently. The server can random-access the index to the first eligible row, then scan the index sequentially over the range of `lastseendate` values.

For similar reasons try this index on devices.

```
CREATE INDEX devices
    ON devices
       (asset_id, stop_time)
```

Comment: so a compound index would be more efficient than 4 individual indexes on each of those columns?  Is it better to do both things?

Comment: Try it. It's hard to know without having your data in hand. But this sort of compound index is often the solution to a full table scan (seq scan) slowdown. Lots of single column indexes often don't help a lot.

Comment: Updated the explain to use production data.

Comment: I added the indexes you recommended - which did provide a small improvement.  However, the query is still extremely slow.